# ImageReader cannot be read by Camera2 - preview works but no output possible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2

In short I can display preview from camera. I add SurfaceView surface and ImageReader surface inside `createCaptureSession()`.

[image]

However I cannot read output provided by ImageReader so as a result ImageReader's listener doesn't catch images.

If if add ImageReader to `createCaptureRequest()` then the my app crashes with error code 4 (commented line in the code).

I work on Android emulator Pixel 3a API 31 with Google Play.

Here is main code related to camera's code. I open the camera and session:

```
openCamera(camManager, frontCamera, cameraHandler) { camera ->
    myCamera = camera

    val imgReader = createNewInstanceOfImageReader(desiredWidth, desiredHeight)

    imgReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
        reader.acquireNextImage()?.let { image ->
            analyzeImageWhenAvailable(image.toBitmap())
            image.close()
        }
    }, imageReaderHandler)

    createSession(imgReader) { session ->
        Logger.debug(TAG, "Session created")

        val createCaptureRequest =
            myCamera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)

        val builder =
            createCaptureRequest.apply {
                addTarget(surfaceView.holder.surface)
                //addTarget(imgReader.surface) // Uncommenting it causes crash of the app. Without it I am able to see the preview.
            }

        session.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), null, cameraHandler)
    }
}
```

This is description of openCamera function:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun openCamera(
    camManager: CameraManager,
    frontCamera: String,
    cameraHandler: Handler,
    onOpened: (camera: CameraDevice) -> Unit
) {
    camManager.openCamera(frontCamera, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) = onOpened(camera)

        override fun onClosed(camera: CameraDevice) {
            Logger.debug(TAG, "cameraStateCallback::onClosed() called")
            resetValues()
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
            Logger.warning(TAG, "onDisconnected() called with: camera = $camera")
            resetValues()
        }

        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
            Logger.error(TAG, "onError() called with: camera = $camera, error = $error")
            resetValues()
        }
    }, cameraHandler)
}
```

This is createSession function:

```
private fun createSession(
    imgReader: ImageReader,
    onSession: (cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) -> Unit
) {
    val captureStateCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            onSession(session)
        }

        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            Logger.error(TAG, "CameraCaptureSession failed while configuring!")
        }
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val targets = listOf(
            OutputConfiguration(imgReader.surface),
            OutputConfiguration(surfaceView.holder.surface),
        )

        myCamera.createCaptureSession(
            SessionConfiguration(
                SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR,
                targets,
                backgroundExecutor,
                captureStateCallback
            )
        )
    } else {
        val targets = listOf(
            surfaceView.holder.surface,
            imgReader.surface
        )

        myCamera.createCaptureSession(
            targets,
            captureStateCallback,
            cameraHandler
        )
    }
}
```

The only error I get is this:

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): cancelRequest:507: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38)
    at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1179)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:99)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1287)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:579)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:790)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:259)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:507: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38) (code 10)
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2439)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
    at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:749)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:97)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1287) 
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:579) 
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:790) 
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:259) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

There is also another error returned by `CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()` in function `onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int)`. Error code is 4.

I am totally lost. I think I am mixing two things (creating sessions and requests) and somehow ImageReader fails causing a crash of the app. Maybe I am blocking any "pipe"?

How could I solve my problem so the image reader would be able to catch images by its listener without crashing the app and to be able to display the preview at once?

Comment: can you share exact crash stack. Ideally you should be able to use these targets togather

Comment: It works for physical device and adding two targets is fine. It is not on the emulator.

Comment: I will provide more information soon although there isn't too much.

Comment: `CameraDevice.StateCallback()` returns error code 4 in function `override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int)`.